# Is there any way to update a progress bar without using a background thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I have a long calculation that happens in a button click event, and after each iteration, I want the progress bar to update.  I was wondering if there is any way to do this without using a background thread:

```
private void btnGetData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            progressBarGetData.Minimum = 0;
            progressBarGetData.Maximum = recordCount;
            progressBarGetData.Value = 0;

            while(long iteration going on)
            {
                //do work
                progressBarGetData.Value += 1;
            }
 }//end button click
```

The progress bar doesn't increment slowly on the screen. Do I have to use a background worker?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the progress bar that's the main problem - it's the fact that you're performing a long-running synchronous operation in the UI thread. That will freeze the whole UI, giving a terrible user experience.

If you can convert your loop to use asynchronous calls (e.g. if it's only long-running because it's talking to web services or a database) then that's one option - and one which is made *much* easier in .NET 4.5.

Otherwise, you *will* need a separate thread - either started explicitly or using [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Comment: Okay, I guess I will have to stop being a sissy and use threading.  Thanks for the post!